# Is it possible to simplify this sum? (maybe an integral representation?)

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, binomial-theorem

For a function $f(x)$ defined for all $x\geqslant 0$, a constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$, is there a way to simplify the following summation?
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 0}^{n} f^{(i)}(x) \frac{c^{-i}}{(n - i)!~i!},
\end{align}
where $f^{(i)}$ is the $i$th derivative of $f$.

It looks kind of like the Taylor series of $f$ but I don't know where to begin.

Can anyone please give a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We observe that
$$
\begin{align}
S &= \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{i=0}^n \left({n\choose i}f^{(i)}(x)c^{-i} \right)  \\
&= \frac{1}{n!}\exp\left(-\frac{x}{c}  \right)\cdot \left(\exp\left(\frac{x}{c}  \right)\sum_{i=0}^n \left({n\choose i}f^{(i)}c^{-i} \right)\right)   \tag{1}\\
\end{align}
$$
And we have

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(f(x)\exp\left(\frac{x}{c}  \right)  \right) = \exp\left(\frac{x}{c}  \right)\sum_{i=0}^n \left({n\choose i}f^{(i)}c^{-i} \right)\tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we deduce that
$$S = \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{c}}}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(f(x)e^{\frac{x}{c}} \right)$$

You can verify this final formula for $n=1,2,3,...$

Comment: Thank you. I have some problems showing formulation (2) holds. Could you please tell me how I can show that?

Comment: @CastsHammer You can prove the formula 2 by recurrence. Try with n = 2. For n = k-1, suppose it works, you can prove easily that it works also for the case n = k.